# can't use oauth bearer token in Service Fabric web API stateless service

Tags: oauth, azure-service-fabric, bearer-token

I have a web API authorized with bearer token returned from token service. When I convert it to service fabric web API stateless service, I can't get claims in controller. I passed the token in the authorization header in the client.

I am wondering what is the correct way to use oauth bearer token in service fabric

Comment: Post some code!

Comment: Since Service Fabric just acts as the host process for the web api it should not interfere with your authorization process. I would take a careful look at the converted code. So, to answer your question, since service fabric does not doe anything other that host your api there is no correct way to use oauth bearer token in service fabric since there is no relation of influence between those two.

Comment: Have you actually ported everything across? Are you missing a delegating handler or middleware registration, or a method or controller level attribute? Have you inspected the headers on the request object when debugging? Are you hitting the SF cluster directly via Azure Load Balancer, via Application Gateway or via any other component that can mess with the http request?

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue. PFB code under startup.cs

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {

```
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        **var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        ConfigureOAuth(appBuilder);
        appBuilder.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);**

    }
    public void **ConfigureOAuth**(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

    }
```

Error : Could not resolve a service of type 'Owin.IAppBuilder' for the parameter 'appBuilder' of method 'Configure' on type 'AuthenticationService.Startup